Choosing a sample for a chi-square test of independence
I have about 2000 observations for a dataset I am working on. There are some categorical variables and a dichotomous outcome variable.
I am trying to get the predictors. Can I use the entire dataset (instead of a sample) to develop a chi-square test of independence to determine the association between two categorical variables?
Thanks.

Hi @EngineerP. You say "I am trying to get the predictors". Can you clarify the predictors of what? What are you trying to achieve?

Hi, I am trying to get the significant features for the outcome variable. I will try to determine the relevance between the categorical variable and the outcome variable and then use simple logistic regression for the numerical variables.

My bad, I didn't see you were mentioning that the dichotomous variable is your outcome of interest. You shouldn't repost a question you've already asked: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/644920/what-is-the-best-method-to-determine-the-significant-features-for-an-outcome-var . A thing you can do is to edit your original question to add more details about what you've tried so far. You should also read about other threads about [tag:model-selection], e.g. you might be interested in this one https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/632925 or this one  https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/444261

Thanks again! This question is different. What I am trying to determine is if I could use the population for a chi-square test of independence instead of a sample. Appreciate your input!

Why would you subsample the data? Why do you call it the population?

Never mind, there is no need for subsampling. Can I generate the frequency table and just use the chi-square test of independence? Thanks for the input!
